# Longest Common Prefix in an array of Strings

Tags: java, algorithm, interview-questions

Please be brutal, and treat this as if I was at an interview at a top 5 tech firm.

> **Question:** Write a function to find the longest common prefix string
>   amongst an array of strings.

Time it took: 17 minutes

Worst case complexity analysis: n possible array elements, each can have length m that we are traversing, hence O(n*m); m could be a constant, since it's rare to find a string with length, so in a sense, I imagine this could be treated as O(n *constant length(m)) = O(n)?

Space complexity analysis: O(n)

```
public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
    String longestPrefix = "";
    if(strs.length>0){
        longestPrefix = strs[0];
    }
    for(int i=1; i<strs.length; i++){
        String analyzing = strs[i];
        int j=0;
        for(; j<Math.min(longestPrefix.length(), strs[i].length()); j++){
            if(longestPrefix.charAt(j) != analyzing.charAt(j)){
                break;
            }
        }
        longestPrefix = strs[i].substring(0, j);
    }
    return longestPrefix;
}
```

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getCommonPrefix%28java.lang.String...%29, http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#line.6682

Comment: @palacsint... helpful.  Even more helpful (for slow people like me): `getCommonPrefix`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pure functions should generally be declared `static`.

You shouldn't need to take substrings in a loop — that's inefficient.  Think of scanning a two-dimensional ragged array of characters.  Check that all of the first characters match, then that all of the second characters match, and so on until you find a mismatch, or one of the strings is too short.

```
public static String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strings) {
    if (strings.length == 0) {
        return "";   // Or maybe return null?
    }

    for (int prefixLen = 0; prefixLen < strings[0].length(); prefixLen++) {
        char c = strings[0].charAt(prefixLen);
        for (int i = 1; i < strings.length; i++) {
            if ( prefixLen >= strings[i].length() ||
                 strings[i].charAt(prefixLen) != c ) {
                // Mismatch found
                return strings[i].substring(0, prefixLen);
            }
        }
    }
    return strings[0];
}
```

Space complexity: O(1).

Worst-case time complexity: O(*n m*) to scan every character in every string.

Comment: is my worst correct?

Comment: O(_n m_) is optimal, due to the nature of the problem. Your original solution may or may not be O(_n m_), [depending on how `String.substring()` works](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16123446/1157100). Since Java 7, it's worse.

Comment: would you hire me with the code I wrote? (Fresh out of college)?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't immediately disqualify you. An interview is not an exam where you get one chance to write something and hand it in. A good interviewer would challenge you to improve on it and gauge your reaction.

Comment: To avoid checking lengths throughout, do a one-time scan to find the shortest string.

Comment: Just an idea and i haven't checked it really would but do you reckon that instead of checking characters 1 then 2 then 3 etc, one could check using some kind of binary search logic : get the length of the adjust string l then consider the character at position l/2 ? The worst case would be home n*log(m) but the average case would be worst on a truly random string distribution where the linear search would stop after a couple of iterations.

Comment: @Josay I don't see how it could be possible to arrive at an answer without verifying the first _m_ characters of all _n_ strings.

Comment: Indeed. I completely missed that point :-/

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments of another answer, no one would decide to hire you after writing a few lines of code.  I basically can't really tell if you are competent or not from those few lines.

Personally, if I were asked to do something like this in an interview, I would start by saying that I would first look in Apache Commons and Google Guava since they probably already have some functions to do such a task and it would be a waste of developer time ($) to rewrite something like this.  Then I would do the exercise.  Maybe others could comment here, because that might get you in trouble more than anything else.

There is a very tiny detail which I noticed: you are not consistent about having spaces or not around `=`, `<` or `>`.  It's a very small detail, but, to me, it means that you don't code that much and you have never figured out which to pick.

Comment: I would never penalize a candidate--especially one fresh out of college--for "failing" to point out that there's probably a well-rested library to solve any problem.  I *would* make a positive note if they mentioned likely candidates, but this is something I can easily teach to a new hire so it's minor. I'm happy to assume that most candidates would assume that when I ask them to write code in an interview...I'm asking them to *write code*. Much of my work involves writing reusable code, and this is a common interview technique.

Answer (score 5):

A few notes about the original code which was not mentioned earlier:

1. From *Clean Code, Chapter 2: Meaningful Names*:

   > **Method Names**
   >
   > Methods should have verb or verb phrase names like postPayment, deletePage, or save.
   >   Accessors, mutators, and predicates should be named for their value and prefixed with get, set, and is according to the javabean standard.

   So, I'd rename the method to `getLongestCommonPrefix`.
2. For the method declaration:

   > ```
   > public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
   > ```

   You could use varargs here:

   ```
   public static String getLongestCommonPrefix(String... strs) {
   ```

   So the method could be called without creating arrays:

   ```
   getLongestCommonPrefix("aaa", "aab");
   ```
3. The method currently throws a `NullPointerException` when one of the parameters is `null`. It would be more friendly to the users to simply return an empty string.
4. You have a variable for `strs[i]`:

   > ```
   > String analyzing = strs[i];
   > ```

   You could use that here too:

   > ```
   > for(; j<Math.min(longestPrefix.length(), strs[i].length()); j++){
   > ```

[Don't do premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/36726) but it's interesting to see what other experts used to optimize 
`StringUtils.getCommonPrefix` in Apache Commons Lang. ([javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getCommonPrefix%28java.lang.String...%29), [source](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#line.6682))

1. You can have a short-circuit path to avoid calling `Math.min` on every iteration. (Applies to *200_success*'s solution and the one in Apache Commons):

   > ```
   > // find the min and max string lengths; this avoids checking to make
   > // sure we are not exceeding the length of the string each time through
   > // the bottom loop.
   > ```
2. They have a guard clause for `null`s and empty strings:

   ```
   // handle lists containing some nulls or some empty strings
   ```

   For cases when it gets an array where the first elements are long strings but last one is an empty one.

Comment: wow, you taught me something new; had no clue that var args even existed(although I'd seen them before, I just thought it was some hack!)

Comment: get* is for accessors. This is not an accessor.